# Find tangent planes to $z = xy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find all planes that are tangent to the surface $z = xy$, pass through $P = (0,0,\frac{1}{2})$ and make an angle of $3\pi/4$ with the $xy$ plane

My Attempt:
The tangent planes to $z = xy$ at some point $(x_0, y_0)$ has the form $z - x_0y_0 = y_0(x - x_0) + x_0(y - y_0)$

The plane that pass through $P$ has the form $ax + by + c(z - \frac{1}{2}) = 0$

Since the plane makes an angle of $3\pi/4$ with $z = 0$, its normal vector and the $xy$ plane normal vector also make an angle of $3\pi/4$. This gives me $|\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}| = cos(3\pi/4)$

However, I cant seem to connect all the information I have together!

Comment: Perhaps you should start by using the normal vector  to the tangent plane in your third step.

Comment: Does that mean I can use $c = 1$ and it leaves me with $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{y_0^2 + x_0^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|$? Then how would I use the information that the tangent plane also pass through point $P$? Thank you!

Comment: Be careful with signs. So forget your $a,b,c$ and use the equation of your tangent plane with $P$.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the sign, the normal vector of the tangent plane is $(y_0,x_0, 1)$ and the normal vector of $xy$ plane is $(0,0,1)$ which means their dot product is non negative, so cannot make an angle of $3\pi/4$? I am not sure where my thinking process is wrong..

Comment: Ohh nevermind, I got the tangent plane normal vector wrong, it should be $(y_0, x_0, -1)$. So if I used all information, I arrived at the equation of the tangent plane is $y_0(x) + (\pm \sqrt{2 - y^2})(y)) - (z - \frac{1}{2}) = 0$. Can I conclude  that this is all the planes I need to find, just need to let $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$? Thank you!

Comment: That equation is wrong. Use the vector dot product to find all points where the angle between the normals is right. *Then* find which of those points have a tangent plane that passes through the given point. You should completely avoid working with the equations of planes. You love those too much!